# .NET Core dependency tree for specific version

Tags: .net-core, dependency-management

I have multiple projects where I have to deal with some security vulnerabilities that exist in the libraries that are transitive dependencies of .NET Core.

I need to know which of these vulnerabilities are resolved in newer .NET Core versions by using newer versions of the libraries in question.

I would like to know if any of these is possible:

- get complete dependency tree of a given .NET Core version
- find which version of a specific library a given .NET Core version is using
- find in which version of .NET Core a specific version of the library is used

Comment: Given .NET Core's lifecycle, shouldn't you be updating to the latest Current or LTS patch level anyway? If you use .NET Core 3.0 or 2.2.x, you're already using an unsupported runtime

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Probably you're right, unfortunately simply updating everything is not an option for me.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Basically to even consider the update decision I need to know in advance what I wrote above.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by dependencies. For NuGet dependencies, `assets.json` contains all transient dependencies. References directly added by the developer are the developer's responsibility. Runtime dependencies are documented in the runtime's release notes.

Comment: what i do is, If i am using .net core 2.2 i change every library version to 2.2. Just edit the csproj file and set everything to 2.2. see what happens lol. take a backup before though
@PanagiotisKanavos
sometimes our solution is using packages that aren't yet supported by the latest .net runtime so we can't just update it all the time

Comment: @zetawars Right, I was thinking about this. I would prefer a solution that doesn't require any such actions from my side

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos NuGet. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.OData/ would be an example.